# Using concatenation with exec

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to using exec and concatenation. I am getting the error incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.  I have played around moving the quotes but have had no luck.

exec('select'''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')),'''+@col_name+''' from [x3v7].[LIVE].'+@tab_name+'''Group BY'+@col_name+'''Having max(len('+@col_name+'))>12''')

Answer (score 0):

```
exec('select  '+@col_name + ',max(len('+@col_name+')),'+@col_name+' from [x3v7].[LIVE].'+@tab_name+' Group BY '+@col_name+' Having max(len('+@col_name+'))>12')
```

Comment: I am passing '+@tab_name+'  can I store this in my query results so I see the table name associated with the max column and column name from results abouve.  thanks

Comment: I afraid not possible :(

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25717841)